# How to clear a text document automatic daily

Tags: php, html, file

I have a text document where I save data from a input field and I want the text document to clear it self every day. Is there any complete method for this?

Comment: using html i am not sure this can be done. i would use php to clear the file and add that file to cronjob to execute it daily.

Comment: Oh missed to add the tag "php". Okay so with cronjob I can do this? @reza

Comment: yes. you can. cronjob will schedule a task when to execute

Comment: Depending on the operating system, crontab, or some other similar method can run a batch/script to copy an empty file over the one you want emptied, or perhaps, if you decide, you can rename the existing file with a date and keep it around as long as you like, and then copy the empty file to replace it.  You could also delete any saved versions after some period to limit the space taken by those files.  Just a thought.